# Threadpool deadlock with Task.Result

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool, deadlock

We have a large legacy with asp.net system, we have started using some async methods from an infrastructure library that we cannot change.
The system doesn't use tasks in most places but the infrastructure exposes only async methods.

In the code we use the following pattern to use the async methods:

`Task.Run(() => Foo()).Result`

We use the [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent a deadlock if somewhere in the code someone didn't use ConfigureAwait(false), There are a lot of places that someone could have missed and it has happened before.
And we use [Task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) to integrate it with the existing sync code base.

After experiencing heavy load We've noticed that that we are getting timeouts but the servers are not doing any work(Low CPU), we've found out that when there are a lot of calls to the server and the thread pool reaches the maximal number of threads the threads reach a deadlock in the Task.Result as it blocks the thread until the task is finished but the task can't run as there are no thread pool threads available to run it.

The best solution would be to change the code to work async all the way, but that is not an option right now.
Also removing the Task.Run could work but it's too risky as there is not enough test coverage to know that we will not cause new deadlocks in untested flows.

I've tried to implement a new task scheduler that will not use the thread pool but a different set of threads to run the Foo task, but internal task are being executed on the default task scheduler that I do not want to replace.

Any ideas how this can be resolved without a huge change to the code base?

This is a small sample app that reproduces the issue, using only 10 threads and not the real limit. In the sample Foo will never be called.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(10, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallBack);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void CallBack(object state)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        var result = Task.Run(() => Foo()).Result;
    }

    public static async Task<string> Foo()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but it looks like this only solves the normal deadlock on a single thread, but it still runs the tasks on the tread pool which causes the deadlock we experience now.

Comment: Iv'e added the QueueSynchronizationContext and used it as follows:
`private static void CallBack(object state)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    using (var ctx = new QueueSynchronizationContext())
    {
        ctx.WaitFor(Foo(), 30000);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo() done.");
    }
}`
But it never reaches the return in Foo.

Comment: _"The best solution would be to change the code to work async all the way, but that is not an option right now"_ -- what do you consider "all the way" and "not an option"? In your example, the obvious fix is to change `Callback()` to `async` and `await` the `Task.Run()`. Fact is, synchronously waiting via `Result` on a `Task` is such a bad idea because it _does_ practically guarantee you'll eventually run into a deadlock problem.

Comment: You seem to be worrying about the wrong thing here. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is only a _deadlock_ problem if you have synchronous waiting-on-Result bugs elsewhere. You're _introducing_ that very bug right here. Do you see the irony? Frankly, unless you can change to `await` instead of using `Result`, I don't see any good solution to this, and there are too many awkward/bad solutions for this question to not be "too broad" otherwise.

Comment: All the way as to change the asp.net http handlers to use tasks and propagate the change to the entire code baseand tIt is not an option as the code base is huge and doesn't support tasks in most cases, and we do not have the option to change it all to async code as it requires to change a very large section of the code that is not covered by tests and is too big of a risk...

Comment: @BarakHirsch seems like Task.Delay [requires](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L4754) free thread pool thread for completion... -:(

Comment: You can limit those kind of threadpool starvation issues by having another threadpool, with a limited size and preallocated threads. Instead of using `Task.Run` to execute the child task, you would use your custom task factory. This way, the child tasks and the main application won't fight for threads. However, it will only work if the child task **isn't** using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, otherwise it'll go back to the threadpool and you won't solve anything

Comment: For a high level understanding of the situation, you must know that the threadpool has two queues: the thread's local queue, and the global queue. Whenever a thread is free, it'll first look for work in its own local queue, then in the global queue if it finds nothing, and then steal work from other threads local queues if there's still nothing. When you use `await`, the work is added to the local queue (so that it stays on the same thread as much as possible). The problem is that ASP.NET uses the global queue to schedule the incoming work. [...]

Comment: When you reach the threadpool limit and its size increases, new threads are created. They'll take work from the global queue (the incoming requests) instead of the local queue (the continuations) : since they're newborn threads, they can't possibly have something in their local queue. Which means that you keep accepting new requests and never completing them, leading to the issue you're observing. Unfortunately, there is no perfect solution (except the full migration to task model and complete removal of synchronous wait, which can take months/years depending on the size of the codebase)

Comment: @BarakHirsch: If you're running into scaling issues and will not apply the proper solution (converting to `async`), then your only other real solution is to upgrade the hardware and inflate the minimum number of thread pool threads.

Answer (score 4):

You have explained your issue very well.

As you are using `Task.Run` then blocking on the result, you are using 1-2 threads, when really with async you want to use 0-1 threads.

If you are using `Task.Run` too liberally through your code then there is a chance you'll have multiple layers of blocking threads, making thread usage get really ugly fast, and you'll hit the maximum capacity as you've described.

As an aside, forget trying to find async deadlocks in unit tests (or console apps) as it requires as non-default `SynchronizationContext`.

The best and right solution would be to make everything top-to-bottom async or sync, but given you are constrained, I'd suggest investigating [this wonderful library from the Microsoft vs team](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/) and look at `JoinableTaskFactory.Run(...)`, this will run continuations on the blocking thread, and plays well when you nest this pattern at multiple levels. Using this approach, you will get closer to the synchronous equivalent code.

To reiterate, these techniques are workarounds, and if you are justifying these workarounds by respecting the existing code, the best way to respect it is to do it right, and make it fully sync, or top-to-bottom async.

Comment: To the person that down-voted, please let me know what you'd like addressed.

Comment: I'm doing this only to call library functions for which there is only an async version.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use short form (`Foo().Result`) instead of `Task.Run(() => Foo()).Result` if you disable `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` setting:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Disabling task-friendly synchronization context means that HttpContext.Current would be null after any await operator - but now it is null inside of Task.Run.

Using `Foo().Result` instead of `Task.Run(() => Foo()).Result` will lead to 2 times less thread pool usage, so it can solve your problem.

Also you can use [`<httpRuntime>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`<processModel>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1(v=vs.100).aspx) to configure minimum free thread pool size:

```
<system.web>
  <processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="..." maxIoThreads="..." />
  <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="..." />
</system.web>
```

Note that default values are:

> maxWorkerThreads = 100 per cpu
>
> maxIoThreads = 100 per cpu
>
> minFreeThreads = 88 per cpu

Comment: I can't use aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext=false because there are places that we do use tasks and the HttpContext.Current.
Changing the number of threads could be a good workaround to when we have a heavy load, but it's not a full solution. I'll check it out

Comment: Shouldn't it be simply `Foo()`, and not `Foo().Result`, with the `Task.Run` removed?

Comment: If `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` is `false`, then you *cannot* use `async`/`await`.

Comment: @StephenCleary why?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Because [when it's `false`, the behavior of `async` is undefined](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/).

Comment: In fact, if you set `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to false and await a task that will complete after the request has ended (because of a timeout for instance), you will crash the process. So yeah, it's better if you don't.